# Replacing Node in LinkedList not actually replacing anything

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am currently writing an implementation of a doubly linked list and am having trouble setting a node to a certain value. Since the data in the nodes is final, I need to replace the entire node, but the code that I wrote for that seems to be working until it exits the method and the original list hasn't been changed at all. Is there anything that I'm missing in the code here?

```
`public void set(int index, String item) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            Node curr = this.front;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                curr = curr.next;
            }
            Node temp = new Node(item);
            temp.prev = curr.prev;
            temp.next = curr.next;
            curr = temp;
        }`
```

Comment: if *data in the nodes is final* then how would you expect *original list hasn't been changed at all* ?

Comment: I can print out the list before and after the set method is called, nothing changes

Comment: Do you share your 'Node' class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also change "`next` of the previous node" and "`prev` of the next node". Assume `prev` is the previous node of `cur` and `next` is the next node of `cur`.

```
Node temp = new Node(item);
temp.prev = prev;
temp.next = next;
next.prev = temp;
prev.next = temp;
```

You should deal with edge problems.

Comment: If the temp.next or temp.prev are null this breaks, are these expected edge cases?

Comment: Yes, for example, what if your ```index``` is ```0``` or ```size - 1```, what if there is only one or two nodes in your list? These are edge cases you should deal with carefully.

Comment: And ```temp.next``` and ```temp.prev``` are always null since it is a new node, maybe you mean ```prev``` and ```next```?

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
 System.out.println(curr.val);
```

and you find the print is actually the same as item

but when you return ,you will find nothing change

you just need find the pre node of curr and set pre.next= curr(where is changed)

```
`public void set(int index, String item) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node curr = this.front;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        Node temp = new Node(item);
        temp.prev = curr.prev;
        temp.next = curr.next;
        curr = temp;
        //here you need to set maybe 
         // Node tmp=curr.prev;
         // tmp.next=curr;
    }`
```